# mysql select where value match exists or does not exist

Tags: mysql

Ok.  The question title sounds strange.  I know.  I don't know the correct verbiage to use.  In my output, 'Pay' is not always available.  There will be circumstances where there is no field to match.  In such a case, I want to still show the other results.

Here is an example output from the current query, in which there are always matches:

```
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
|                    Event Date                    |                      Client                      |                    Event Type                    |                     Location                     |                      Player                      |                       Pay                        |
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
|                01/07/2020 6:00 PM                |                   Invite Test                    |                  Private Party                   |          119 SW 3rd St. Galva, IL 61434          |                   Test Invite                    |                      450.99                      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|               01/30/2020 10:00 PM                |               F&F Test Sales Team                |                     Wedding                      |                     Chicago                      |                   Greg                           |                       2.25                       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                02/21/2020 5:00 PM                |                    Ana Landon                    |          Law school formal party/dance           |                St. Petersburg, FL                |                   Brandon                        |                       500                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                02/21/2020 5:00 PM                |                    Ana Landon                    |          Law school formal party/dance           |                St. Petersburg, FL                |                   Nate                           |                      test2                       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|               03/27/2020 12:00 AM                |             test group for it stuff              |                    IT testing                    |                      Galva                       |                   Test Invite                    |                       500                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                03/14/2020 5:00 PM                |                Kimberly G'Fellers                |     Corporate w/ Full Shells and Uplighting      |                    Aurora, IL                    |                   Robert                         |                       12.50                      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notice all values have a Pay amount.  How can I modify my query to show values that do not have a pay amount?  In other words, there will be no entry `WHERE ux.meta_key = CONCAT('_um_groups_', m.group_id, '_price')` as shown at the end of the query.

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT
  `Event Date`.`Event Date` AS `Event Date`,
  wp_posts.post_title AS Client,
  Type.`Event Type` AS `Event Type`,
  Location.Location AS Location,
  wp_users.display_name AS Player,
  ux.meta_value AS Pay
FROM wp_um_groups_members m
  INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ux
    ON m.user_id1 = ux.user_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_posts
    ON m.group_id = wp_posts.ID
  LEFT JOIN wp_users
    ON m.user_id1 = wp_users.ID
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
      wp_postmeta.post_id,
      wp_postmeta.meta_value AS `Event Date`
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_um_groups_event_start') `Event Date`
    ON `Event Date`.post_id = wp_posts.ID
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
      wp_postmeta.post_id,
      wp_postmeta.meta_value AS `Event Type`
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_um_groups_event_type') Type
    ON Type.post_id = wp_posts.ID
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
      wp_postmeta.post_id,
      wp_postmeta.meta_value AS Location
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_um_groups_event_location') Location
    ON Location.post_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE ux.meta_key = CONCAT('_um_groups_', m.group_id, '_price')
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will add a fiddle.  I was not aware of that.  Also, I would have asked this follow-up question in my original, but I felt like you had helped me with  my original question and I didn't want to make it too confusing.  Anyhow, I'll create that fiddle now.

Comment: It's better this way.